# Postgres CROSS JOIN JSON_TO_RECORD, JSON_EACH

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use Postgres to generate the following output

```
ONE    TWO      THREE
=====================
A1     A2       A3
B1     B2       B3
```

from the following JSON

```
{"metadata" : { 
     "A" : { "one" : "A1" , "two" : "A2", "three" : "A3" }, 
     "B" : { "one" : "B1" , "two" : "B2", "three" : "B3" }
 }}
```

I have this SQL statement

```
select *
  from JSON_TO_RECORD(value) as REC(ONE TEXT, TWO TEXT, THREE TEXT) 
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSON_EACH(
   '{"metadata" : { 
       "A" : { "one" : "A1" , "two" : "A2", "three" : "A3" }, 
       "B" : { "one" : "B1" , "two" : "B2", "three" : "B3" }
    }}'::json -> 'metadata');
```

When I execute in PSQL I get

```
ERROR:  column "value" does not exist
LINE 2:  from JSON_TO_RECORD(value) as REC(ONE TEXT, TWO TEXT, THREE...
```

My understand is that JSON_EACH outputs a results set with 2 columns, key and value and I should be able to pass value to the JSON_TO_RECORD operator. What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't have a `FROM` for the table containing the `value` column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_to_record(value)` must be in a lateral join as it uses `value` from `json_each()`:

```
select rec.*
from json_each(
   '{"metadata" : { 
       "A" : { "one" : "A1" , "two" : "A2", "three" : "A3" }, 
       "B" : { "one" : "B1" , "two" : "B2", "three" : "B3" }
    }}'::json -> 'metadata')
cross join json_to_record(value) as rec(one text, two text, three text) 

 one | two | three 
-----+-----+-------
 A1  | A2  | A3
 B1  | B2  | B3
(2 rows)
```